# Scoring stops and resets game

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a game where you are supposed to move an image between other image without colliding. Everything worked fine until I added coins to the game. When the image hits a coin, it's supposed to make a sound (which it does) and add +1 to the coin label. The problem is, when I add the code to make the coinlabel get +1, the image that I'm moving will stop and go back to starting position. The same thing happened to me when I was using an `NSTimer` (because users playing the app had time on finish the level.) But everytime the label counted a number, the game stopped again and the ball was put back to the starting position.

Here is some code for the game.

```
-(IBAction)left {
    goLeft = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(goLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    if (goLeft == nil) {
        goLeft = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(goLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

-(IBAction)stopLeft {
    [goLeft invalidate]; goLeft = nil;
}

-(void)goLeft {
   image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x -3.5, image.center.y);
{

    //Coins
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(image.frame, coin1.frame)) {
        coin1.hidden = YES;
        [self getcoins];
    }

-(void)getcoins{
    //Here i have a avaudioplayer playing a noise (dont need to show that as that works fine)

    //Then the +1 to label 
    coinlabel.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:([coinlabel.text intValue] + 1)] stringValue];

    // And when i add this and the image hits the coin, the image goes back to the starting position.  But i want it not to stop or anything, but continue.
}
```

The left action is connected to touch down. And stopleft is connected to touch up inside. Hope you understand and thanks for any help.

Comment: You have a debugger. Debug! You can step through your code one line at a time, watching the variable values change, and see exactly what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Could you please add the complete code. And is the image perhaps under autolayout?

Comment: Should i turn off autolayout?:)

Comment: @Kordi Just disabled autolayout and now it works! Thanks, ur the man :)